# How do I get the matching merge pull request for a specific commit?

Tags: github, github-pages

How do I get the matching merge pull request #XXXX for a commit (e.g. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/a81f78d35ecabae6ba61c1a65279bcb5ff9c7d95) in Github?

Many thanks

Comment: Or is there no pull request to the commit https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/a81f78d35ecabae6ba61c1a65279bcb5ff9c7d95 ?